# Get multiline utf-8 data (2900 columns) from R into SPSS

Tags: r, excel, csv, utf-8, spss

Is there a failsafe way to get data with cells containing multiline utf8 text with many columns from R to SPSS? Preferably with conserved types.

- If you say CSV, you may not have tried transferring 2700 columns with the occasional cell containing multiline text and utf8 characters. It seems impossible.

  - SPSS fails if there is the occasional cell containing several lines (will see it as several cases, `DELCASE` doesn't fix this and requires you to know the number of columns).
  - OpenOffice would properly handle charset and multilines but it can't handle that many columns.
  - Excel can deal with many columns. It will open comma-separated files, not tab-separated files correctly by default, but it botches diacritics. If you use the import-feature to fix utf-8 it botches multi-line text.
- If you say `xlsx::write.xlsx`: this works, but takes excruciatingly long (10m) and before SPSS will eat the generated xlsx files, I have to manually open and resave them in Excel (I haven't yet found out what SPSS doesn't like about them, it thinks they're single column).
- I haven't tried setting up a database and using RMySQL + ODBC in Excel or SPSS yet, because it seemed a bit overkill then. Doesn't seem so overkill in comparison anymore, but now I doubt that ODBC will do what it should in Excel or SPSS. Is this a proven way?

**Edit:** in reply to a comment suggesting `foreign::writeForeign`:

writeForeign doesn't save to .sav directly, it saves a CSV file like this `write.table(dfn, file = datafile, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, sep = ",", quote = FALSE, na = "", eol = ",\n")` and generates .sps files for import.

It fails with my original data because my variable names exceed 8 chars (and I would get duplicate names through truncation, not surprising with 2700 vars. SPSS can actually deal with this using the routes I described). If I use a subset designed to exhibit the known pitfalls, it fails with "Cannot handle character variables longer than 255", but I wouldn't be surprised if it failed with multi-line character input in general too, because SPSS doesn't seem to be able to deal with this during CSV import.

Comment: Have you looked at the `foreign` package? I definitely wouldn't use the term "failsafe" to describe it, but it offers the ability to save .sav files directly from R. It has *generally* worked in my experience, but I haven't exactly tried it on complicated datasets.

Comment: @David I replied above. I hadn't tried it for this DF yet, but it didn't work at all (have had problems with it before too). But at least it's aware of its limitations.

Comment: Your reasoning for why CSV fails isn't clear to me. Why does OpenOffice have anything to do with it? SPSS **can** import multiline text data, and another simple solution would be to replace line breaks and/or carriage returns with some sort of known character set and then change them back later even if it couldn't.

Comment: @AndyW OpenOffice's role is simply that I would use it before/instead of Excel to create spreadsheets palatable to SPSS, but it fails with this many columns, while Excel fails with UTF8 characters (+ multiline). Yes, replacing line breaks would potentially be a workaround. But since SPSS can deal with multiline text in cells (in my testing I could not get it to properly import cells with varying numbers of lines from CSV, but please tell me how), I (my boss)'d like to keep new lines (I could do annoying pre- AND post-processing, but then `write.xlsx` route is superior).

Comment: See the syntax reference for `GET DATA`, in particular the `DELCASE` subcommand. If R is providing SPSS syntax along with whatever it is exporting, it is probably as simple as adding that line in for the `GET DATA` statement.

Comment: @AndyW No, it is not that simple. That line, according to the [reference](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/spssstat/v20r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.spss.statistics.help%2Fsyn_get_data_delcase.htm) would be `/DELCASE=VARIABLES 2903`. "Multiple cases can be contained on the same line, and data for one case can span more than one line. A case is defined by the number of variables." The result has garbled cases (but the correct nr of cases and variables, I give you that).

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't gone the ODBC route, because the `xlsx` package works better than expected.

To fix the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` error that you'll get with large tables, I used `options( java.parameters = "-Xmx3g" )` (before the xlsx library is loaded).

That said, I'm still looking for an answer that doesn't involve manually resaving an Excel document.